# How to get the total working hours of a particular project project (foreign key it may duplicate) using sql query

Tags: iphone, sql, oracle, sqlite

Im working on an iPhone application, Using SQLite as the backend

In my application i have two tables, ProjectsTable, Project_Hours_Table in my DB.

[image]

[image]

Here in first table i have list of projects with their unique_id.

In second table i have project ID's (as foreign key) and the respective working hours.

Now my requirement is to get the project_ID's and the sum of that particular project working hours.

**as follows**

```
Project_ID  Hours
1             1
2             0
3             5 (1+4)
4             11 (5+6)
5             2
6             13 (7+6)
7             3
```

can any one please provide suggestions **to implement the query**
thanks in advance

Comment: Try this: `SELECT UNIQUE(Project_id), sum (hours) FROM ProjectHoursTable WHERE Project_ID IN (select prom-id from ProjectsTable)`; may be it can help. And please intimate in case it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Project_Id, 
       sum(Hours) as Hours
  from Proj_HoursTable
group by Project_Id
```

Since both of the required fields are available in Proj_HoursTable, no need to join to ProjectTable. Adding the project name to the output would require a join to ProjectTable (assumes project id and project name are 1 to 1

```
select pjt.ProjName, 
       pht.Project_Id, 
       sum(pht.Hours) as Hours
  from Proj_HoursTable pht join ProjectsTable pjt
    on pjt.Proj_Id = pht.Project_Id
group by pht.Project_Id, pjt.ProjName
```

Answer (score 1):

First You need to display `Proj_Id` for particular project  (That you want  to show total hour) and store it in **variable.**

And then after write query for this

```
select * from Project_Hours_Table  where Proj_Id = Proj_Id
```

This query return all data of specific `Proj_Id` that you need.
and store it data to `NSMutableDictionary`, after you need to get value of **Hour** field by your dictionary `key @"hour"`

you return this value as `NSSting` and you need to convert it in `intValue` by

```
int hourCount = [StringHourValue intValue];

and count it it will give you total number of Hour
```